# Is there a way to see if a Jupiter Notebook has stalled?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook that seems to have been running for a really long time.  It is a web crawler that has produced some output in a file.  However, I am suspecting that it has gotten hung up.  Is there a way to see if it has, or exactly what step it is on while it is running?  I did not see this question already on here so apologies if I missed it.

The below is the output I have in my terminal but I am not sure if it is even relevant to this since it only ever seems to output saving info.  I am new to Juypter notebook so I thank you in advance if this is super obvious.

```
[I 10:30:20.437 NotebookApp] Replaying 3 buffered messages
[I 10:32:16.731 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/WebScraping/EmailScraper.ipynb
[I 10:34:16.734 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/WebScraping/EmailScraper.ipynb
[I 10:35:42.370 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/WebScraping/EmailScraper.ipynb
[I 10:35:55.333 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Desktop/WebScraping/EmailScraper.ipynb
[I 10:35:56.975 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 6bb61915-121a-4be3-a1cb-4f5d58d96ada:d26bdbd2fbf04365860ee52c7c72721a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use  **verbose**

The verbose logs package extends Python's logging module to add the log levels NOTICE, SPAM, SUCCESS and VERBOSE: The NOTICE level sits between the predefined WARNING and INFO levels